# Dropping an index while DML operations in progress

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a script to create an index online on one of the tables that is constantly being accessed by the application. I would like to know, if there is a way for me to drop the index online as well just in case if a back out is required.

I am using Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.4.0

The reason why I am asking this is because if I try to delete the index without taking an exclusive lock it will give `ORA-00054` - resource busy. The oracle doc says I can use online for 12c, is there a way to achieve this in 11g as well? `DROP INDEX [ schema. ] index [ ONLINE ] [ FORCE ] ;`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [ddl_lock_timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams068.htm) (I guess the table won't be locked forever):

> DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT specifies a time limit for how long DDL statements
>   will wait in a DML lock queue

```
alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 1000000;
drop index idxName;
```

Maybe you should consider changing it to INVISIBLE first:

```
ALTER INDEX idName INVISIBLE;
```

Comment: Thank you @vercelli. My index was pretty small and this approach worked just fine. It would be interesting to see how it would work on large index objects though.

Comment: @Ankit Dropping an index should be pretty fast. Once the lock it's acquired by the drop index, the rest of the queries will have to wait